# Results from an cURL request into a form

Tags: php, mysql, api, curl

As mentioned in my previous question I read about cURL and how to work with it. I got the request with the following API: api.openkvk.nl (it's in Dutch, sadly enough) working:

```
$get = $_POST['bedrijfsnaam'];
$get = str_replace(" ","%20",$get);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.openkvk.nl/php/SELECT%20*%20FROM%20kvk%20WHERE%20bedrijfsnaam%20=%20'$get'%20LIMIT%201;");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print("<pre>"); print_r($result); print("</pre>");
$kvks = $result[0]["RESULT"]["ROWS"][0][2];
echo $kvks; 
curl_close($ch);
```

and I got the results back in the following form:

```
array(array("RESULT"=>array("TYPES"=>array("bigint","varchar","int","int","varchar","varchar","varchar","varchar","varchar","varchar","bigint","varchar","decimal","decimal","date"),"HEADER"=>array("kvk","bedrijfsnaam","kvks","sub","adres","postcode","plaats","type","status","website","vestiging","rechtsvorm","lat_rad","lon_rad","anbi"),"ROWS"=>array(array("526937320000","Unicmedia","52693732","0","Terschellingstraat 12","1825ND","Alkmaar","Hoofdvestiging",NULL,NULL,"22611126",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)))))
```

What I want to do is the following:

Put this values from the database: kvks, adres, postcode and plaats in a form (so that I can edit them).

I don't know how to do this. Could you give me an explanation?

PS I'm new with API's so I don't understand everything yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update:

Their API is returning it as a php string - change the part of your URL which says `/php/` to `/json/`.

Then, make it so you have `$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);`

Now the array access should work.

---

To get the value of `kvks`, supposing the value you posted is the in `$result`, you'd use `$kvks = $result[0]["RESULT"]["ROWS"][0][2]`.

(It looks like you're posting the result of a `print_r` - try encasing it in `<pre>` tags when you display it for a much more formatted result)

Since you have PHP getting the values, you could simply output an HTML form with them prefilled:

```
<form action="savedata.php" method="post">
<?php
    echo "<input type='text' name='blah' value=\"" . htmlspecialchars($blah) ."\"><br>";
 ?>
```

Then, if `$blah` is `asdf`, this would output `<input type='text' name='blah' value="asdf">`.

When you submit it to your `savedata.php` method, you'd insert the modified values (now found through `$_POST['blah']`) into your database however you like.

Comment: I'm not echoing something, so how can I stop the array from being displayed? I updated my post so you can see what the cURL code is.

Comment: By default, cURL simply echoes the result.  Not sure why this is default, really.  To make cURL *return* to a value instead of echoing, use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);`.  Then, add `$result = ` before `curl_exec($ch)`.  Then, use `print("<pre>"); print_r($result); print("</pre>");`

Comment: I get the following error when I use `$kvks = $result[0]["RESULT"]["ROWS"][0][2]` : Cannot use string offset as an array.

Comment: Add your `print_r` to your original post.  It's very hard to see the structure when it's all on one line.

Comment: You have to add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);` on the line before curl_exec.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7857/discussion-between-andre-woons-and-tim)

Answer (score 0):

From my experiments it seems this API is returning PHP code, this would have to be eval'd. eval is a very bad idea.

Can I suggest using the JSON method of the API instead, by replacing the /php/ with /json/

The API will then return a JSON string which you can decode into an object / array

You will also need to add `curl_setop($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,0);` to your curl request

Here is some revised code

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.openkvk.nl/json/SELECT%20*%20FROM%20kvk%20WHERE%20bedrijfsnaam%20=%20'$get'%20LIMIT%201;");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$apiResult = json_decode($result, true);
```

$apiResult will now contain an array with your result

A `var_dump($apiResult)` will give you

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'RESULT' => 
        array
          'TYPES' => 
            array
              ...
          'HEADER' => 
            array
              ...
          'ROWS' => 
            array
              ...
```

Now that you have the array, you should easily be able to insert it into a DB.